# How to console the properties of `mongoose`. Where to look for mongoose properties?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I see there are alot of properties on the mongoose object. When I `console.log(mongoose)` I don't see the important things (the common useful things)

I see

```
Mongoose {
  connections:
   [ NativeConnection {
       base: [Circular],
       collections: {},
       models: {},
       config: [Object],
       replica: false,
       hosts: null,
       host: 'localhost',
       port: 27017,
       user: undefined,
       pass: undefined,
       name: 'mytest',
       options: [Object],
       otherDbs: [],
       _readyState: 2,
       _closeCalled: false,
       _hasOpened: false,
       _listening: false,
       db: [Object] } ],
  plugins: [],
  models: {},
  modelSchemas: {},
  options: { pluralization: true } }
```

It shows a connections object inside a Mongoose object but I'm looking for
this stuff

```
console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState)
var gfs = Grid(mongoose.connection.db, mongoose.mongo);
//I could only set up GRIDFS using those paramaters
```

there's no `connection` object (singular) and there is not `mongo` object that I see on a `mongoose` object.

And What does `mongoose.mongo` do and `mongoose.connection.db`. why are they different?

I couldn't find `mongoose.mongo` in mongoose API.

And I have collections in the database but its producing `{}`

I really wanted to see a `connection` or `mongo` property when I did `console.log(mongoose)`. Why isn't it there?

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet

```
// Data base connection 
mongoose.connect(mongoURI, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(chalk.bold.red('Please check you MongoDB instance connection'));
    }
});

const connection = mongoose.connection;

const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
Grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;
```